# Android xml layout file is not being added to R.java

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageNew"
    android:layout_width="50dip"
    android:layout_height="50dip"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>




</LinearLayout>
```

This is my new layout file and it is not being detected by eclipse, nor is it in the R file. I can't create any new layout files or perhaps I'm doing it all wrong. All my older layouts are seen fine.

EDIT:

Also, a layout I had created previously I have edited with a new ID, however that new id is not detected either.

Comment: do a project clean may be  or restart eclipse.

Comment: haha, what a simple solution. Post as an answer and I'll check it off :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9170827/why-is-my-custom-layout-file-not-recognized

instead of android.R just use R...

Comment: I had errors regarding an id not being recognized and it didn't work after the project clean (there were then errors regarding R needing an import). Turns out there was a text file in the drawable folder with a **space in its file name**; after removing the space it worked fine.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Clean your project or restart the eclipse, i guess it's the problem with eclipse automatic building.

Comment: also check whether **Build Automatically** is selected under **Project->Build Automatically**

Answer (score 22):

Look to the imports, the R imported maybe is not correct.

Answer (score 17):

I have this import

```
import android.R;
```

I've deleted this and layout is working again

Comment: thanks it helps .. But why this happened ? can you please explain it

Comment: this happens to me because I use shitft+command+O brainlessly

Comment: Still happening in 2019, kills an hour for me every time

Comment: Oct 2020 checking in. I've popped about five capillaries trying to figure out what's wrong with my code. This fixes it

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I took Eclipse's advice and removed

```
import android.R;
```

And replaced all references to `R` with the fully qualified name `[project-specific package].R` since the R file was actually being generated under some package, and the default contained nothing of interest.

You can check the package name by looking in the gen folder.

Answer (score 1):

If ANYTHING is wrong in your layouts, new updates aren't added to the R file.  Look at the errors panel, and possibly to a clean rebuild to see what errors are popping up.

Your layout xml is fine.  The file itself may have an incompatible name.

Answer (score 1):

My development environment: [ MacBook Pro, Eclipse: 4.4.0]

I've tried all of the above, but no sucess.

Its resolved in the following steps:

Step-1)Comment out `import android.R;`
  Or, 
 Remove it complete.

Step-2) `import packageName.R;`

OR,

`import com.arundhwaj.augmented_reality.R;`

Hope it help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Probably problem in a name xml a file. The name shouldn't contain upper case symbols.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the IDE (Eclipse) added the `import android.R` again and again. I had to update my Android SDK to make that go away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solve it renaming the xml file with lowercase symbols.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and fixed it by adding

```
android:id="@+id/container"
```

underneath

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found out that when I'had just started the project I renamed the package but the refactory function didn't canghe the name of the package of the generated code... so renaming that I corrected the missmatch.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a auto build issue with eclipse. So even if you remove android.R and do clean-build the issue may not go away. And prevent any R.java files to be created in the gen folder

1. Remove import android.R (The R referred should be you package R not the android.R)
2. Make sure the project is error free for a successful build. You can comment out error throwing references to R in project (if on worst case comment all R references).
3. Clean the Project
4. This should remove all the stale references and do a fresh compilation. Once the R.java is generated. Uncomment all R references . Now the layout and other references which were not getting recognized previously should resolve

Answer (score 0):

I changed 
{ android:src="@drawable/Myapp" } to
{ android:src="@drawable/myapp" } in my layout.xml then I could select R.layout.mylayout in Mainactivity.java

Capital letters are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing same issue Just "Clean" the Project it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using android.R.layout. use 
R.layout.new_layout_file

```
EXAMPLE, in arrayadapter **ArrayAdapter<E> item= new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.list_item,array); where E is the object**
```

Answer (score 0):

One more reason that this can happen.  If for example you add a new module and you give it an existing package name, you'll get duplicate BuildConfig.java class files built.  The mergeDexRelease and mergeDexDebug gradle task won't like that and fail with an error "Program type already present" followed by the name of the duplicate class.

If you didn't notice the error, you'll see things like R.id.yourLayout  or R.drawable.yourIcon being undefined in your app.  Ironically string resources can still be found.  The correction is to change the package name in one of the modules with the duplicate name.

If you want to find the locations of the duplicate classes in Android Studio, use "Navigate/Class..." and enter the name of the duplicate class.  You might need to check the "include non-project items"

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just copy pasted the missing xml file in the same layout folder with a different name and suddenly both ids started appearing in R. I guess there must be a temporary issue in generating R. Btw, I was using product flavors not sure if it something related.